# AirPlay doesn't work from laptop, works from iOS device

Tags: itunes, airport-express, airplay

My MBA used to stream music to my speakers via my Airport Express, but recently it stopped working. The speakers over airplay are still visible in iTunes, but when I try to connect, the dialog hangs for about 20 seconds, and then disappears.

Streaming from my iPhone works fine, so the problem is my laptop. The firewall in Lion is turned off. How do I debug this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem was that my connection had a single DNS server set to 127.0.0.1, because I was running a [local DNS server](http://mikeferrier.com/2011/04/04/setting-up-wildcard-dns-on-localhost-domains-on-osx/). Changing this to 8.8.8.8 solved the problem.

iTunes does a DNS lookup for the AirPlay device that's configured, and my settings made that lookup fail.

I haven't managed to get AirPlay working together with a local DNS server though, but that's another question.